# Plotting Vout vs. Vin Curves for an Ideal Diode / Resistor Circuit

Tags: voltage, resistors, diodes

I am trying to plot the Vout vs. Vin for the following circuit, assuming both D1 and D2 are ideal, the forward voltages are V(D1,on) = 0 and V(D2,on) = 0.7V, R1 = R3 = 1 kOhm, R2 = 4K, and E = 3.3V.

[image]

[image]

Comment: This looks like a homework problem, which we don't help with unless there is work already shown.

Comment: I typed my shown work !. I found the values for Vin. now I need to plot but I don't know how !

Comment: Oh thats your work.  Apologies, the way it was typed, it looked like those were the given values.

Comment: only the first diagram was given and the values for Resistors and E. I used Microsoft Visio to plot the second circuit ( open and close the diodes) and typed my answers for clarity  .

Comment: 1. Edit your title..."Electronics Problem" is not very descriptive.
2. Edit your tags. This has nothing to do with power electronics.
3. Please type your question out, reading the tiny print is tiring and will discourage people from answering it.

Comment: You also might want to read my answer to your previous question: http://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/151264/electronics-i-problem which essentially tells you how to plot Vout vs. Vin. You just have to substitute 0 for the D1 forward voltage and model D2 as a real diode.

Comment: You don't need to solve for Vin, but for Vout in terms of Vin ... what would Vout be for various input voltages Vin? In addition, I have a confusion regarding "E=3.3 Volts". The way the voltage source "E" is drawn, the positive terminal would be down. Do you mean the voltage at the anode of D2 relative to GND is +3.3V or -3.3V?

Comment: the voltage of the anode is 3.3 Volts which makes the top right node -3.3 volts.

Comment: I need to plot this and I don't know how I can include the D1 , D2 , Vin , and Vout in the plot , the regions where each diode is ON OFF , and the other three conditions!

Comment: So by D2 being a "real PN junction diode", is it still a diode that turns "ON" instantly at 0.7V (infinite current), or is the IV curve an exponential?

Comment: If the anode is +3.3V wouldn't the top right node be +3.3V? Last time I checked diodes don't invert voltages. Also does D2 have a voltage drop or not? You say it turns on at 0.7V but then don't ever subtract a diode forward voltage from the 3.3V.

Comment: Diode D2 is a real PN junction diode, which can be modeled, when conducting in the forward region, with VDON = 0.7V and forward resistance rD= 0 Ohms

Comment: that was given info from the quesiton

Comment: my apologies, the anode is negative in this case. sorry.

Comment: I mean the anode of D2 is negative , and the top right node is negative also

Comment: I went to prof's office hours and he confirmed that everything up to what I have is correct. now I have no idea how to plot them. can you take it from here and give me some hints so I can plot them? I know that since Vin of D2 is lower than D1 which means D2 switches first. ( in the third quadrant).

Comment: -1 for a really dumb title.

Comment: @ Olin , how do u like it now?

Answer (score 2):

> Diode D2 is a real PN junction diode, which can be modeled, when
>   conducting in the forward region, with VDON = 0.7V and forward
>   resistance rD= 0 Ohms

Since \$r_D\$ = 0, D2 can be modeled as an ideal diode with a forward voltage of 0.7V.

So I'm going to link you to [my answer on your previous question](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/a/151295/26678), in which I explain how you derive the \$V_{out}\$ vs. \$V_{in}\$ curves assuming D1 and D2 are ideal diodes, which they are.

Comment: thanks for your time, but that does not answer my question. I would like to know how I can plot the of Diode on a XY coordinates. having the equations, how can I plot them? my question is about the graphs not analyzing the circuit

Comment: My answer gives you an equation for Vout for all regions of Vin. The only thing I haven't done is plot it for you. 

Unless you are trying to plot something else..

Comment: I know you gave me your equations for the previous problem and I thank you for that. but I cannot plot them ! that is the real question, how can I plot them? can you draw it and explain it how you draw it?

Comment: I'll give you a hint. You have 3 equations for Vout in terms of Vin. In the first region, Vout is constant (just -(E + VD2)). In the second region, Vout is linear with a slope determined by your R2 and R3 values. In the third region, Vout is also linear with a different slope. Plug in some boundary conditions for Vin and fill it out.

Comment: please plot it for me if it is possible !

Comment: No, I won't plot it for you because I want you to do it yourself and learn from it. This site is not a solution manual. I have already analyzed the entire circuit for you.

Comment: I know that that is why I showed my analysis up to the point where I am stuck.